# How to make plotly.express.line lines not to connect between one another?

Tags: python, plotly, line, mapbox

I am new to plotly and I am trying to draw some roads on a map in different colors based on the traffic value.

This is what I tried:

```
fig = px.line_mapbox(lat=test_lat, lon=test_long, hover_name=test_name,mapbox_style = 'carto-positron',color =test_trafic)
fig.show()
```

Where test_lat is an array with latitudes points, test_long is an array with longitudes, test_name are the names of the streets and test_trafic are the values of traffic.

The problem is that, when I run it, although the streets appear correctly on the map, plotly connects all the lines between them like this:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us what `test_lat` and `test_long` look like? Is there a particular shape they are forming, or are randomly selected points?

Comment: They are not randomly selected, they are a list of float values that correctly represents the latitude and longitute of the streets, they are taken from TomTom api, if I plot just the first 200 values, they display correctly. It looks like plotly draws a line between the lines that have the same traffic value. All lists have 1 dimension and have a length of 20000.